# Value of document variable inside shadow dom

Tags: shadow-dom

What is the value of `document` variable inside shadow-dom?
In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/36kypL48/2/)  jsfiddle we can see that it searches for the `app` node in the parent document and alerts its value. Does that mean that shadow-dom doesn't have a separate document variable and can access parent's document?

Comment: Yes, if you want isolation you need IFRAMEs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here, the shadow DOM can access the parent 'document':
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

[image: Shadow DOM - MDN]